# navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition return null

Tags: cordova

I have a problem about the geolocation cordova. I am currently developing an application that uses geolocation phone, but geolocation function will always in the error function and when I log on error I have this:

```
PositionError {code: null, message: ""}
```

Here is my function:

```
var getGeoLocation = function() {
                if (typeof(navigator.geolocation) != 'undefined') {
                    try{
                        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
                            var lat = position.coords.latitude;
                            var lng = position.coords.longitude;
                            alert(lat + "/" + lng);    
                        },function(err) {
                            console.log(err);    
                        });
                    }
                    catch(e){
                        alert(e);
                    }
                }
            }
            getGeoLocation();
```

I'm on IntelXDK with version 4.0 of cordova. The org.apache.cordova.geolocation plugin is installed.
I looked all over the internet before posting the question but I have found absolutely nothing :/

If anyone know the reason for the bug I would be very grateful.

Thanks,

Comment: When are you calling the function? Is it possible that you call the function before the "deviceready" event was fired?

Comment: I make the call in a js file share but this call therefore well after the event "deviceready" because it thereby to click a button after two other pages. And the file is correctly called for if I put a log above and below the call of getGeolocation () function they appear good.

Comment: Do you have geolocation active on your phone?

Comment: yes, I've tried with and without the geolocation active and with and without wifi connected :/

Comment: i've tried to create another project but i will same error :/

Comment: Try html 5geolocation apk it doesn't need the plugin

Comment: have you tried it with high accuracy ? test it with these options { maximumAge: 3000, timeout: 10000, enableHighAccuracy: true }

Comment: html5 geolocation? it's navigator.geolocation no?

Comment: yes i have tried with high accuracy but not working to :/ but I just tried it on an iPad and it works: / do nothing understandable because it does not work on android but it works well on iPad